# getline no me deja ingresar texto

Tags: c++

estoy utilizando el siguiente trozo de código en el cual introduzco una cadena y se guarda en el archivo pero no deja guardar ningún carácter en la cadena por que no pausa, se ejecuta las instrucciones que van después

```
 const size_t longitud = 100;
 char nota[longitud];
 fstream archivo(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO.c_str());
 if(archivo.good()) {
   archivo.open(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO.c_str(), fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
 } else {
   archivo.open(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO.c_str(), fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
 }

 cout << "\n\t  Ingrese la nota porfavor" << " ." << endl;
 cin.getline(nota, longitud);
 archivo << nota << endl;
 archivo.close();
 break;
```

Comment: pude tratar se añadir `cin.ignore();` antes de `cin.getline();` justo debajo de std.cout.Saludos

Comment: gracias eso funciono pero no me guarda la información en el archivo

Comment: la verdad es que ahora mismo no puedo probar su codigo, pero esta parte me tiene confundido `fstream::in | fstream::out | app` no se si al usar los dos al mismo tiempo genera un error o por el contrario es valido, puede tratar de usar solo uno de los dos por ejemplo `fstream::in |`. Se que en un standar de  c++ no recuerdo cual "creo que el uso de in | app " no es valido pero no puedo acegurarselo. Saludos

Comment: Que standard de C++ esta usando, por ejemplo C++98, C++03, C++17? quizas tenga que ver con el comportamiento que esta experimentando. Saludos

Comment: uso c++11 y en linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que su error esta por aqui:

```
fstream archivo(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO.c_str());
```

cambiarlo por ejemplo por `fstream archivo;`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/fstream/

Esto es para que haga una comprovacion es un simple test basado en su codigo, si este le funciona quizas el error esta en otra parte de su codigo.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    const size_t longitud = 100;
    char nota[longitud];

    fstream archivo; //<- Cambiar

    if(archivo.good()) {
       archivo.open("/home/SuHome/t.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app); //Ponga la ruta de su home para test

     } else {

       archivo.open("/home/SuHome/t.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc); //Ponga la ruta de su home para test
     }

     cout << "\n\t  Ingrese la nota porfavor" << " ." << endl;

     cin.ignore();// A mi que me funciono sin esto.

     cin.getline(nota, longitud);
     archivo << nota << endl;
     archivo.close();

return 0;
}
```

Esto deberia de crear un fichero sin problemas.

P.D: Compruebe que ajusta esta parte para su SO -> `archivo.open("/home/SuHome/t.txt"....` usando su directorio de usuario.

Comment: es exactamente eso muchas gracias

Comment: @soldat25 me alegra que lo solucionaras. Saludos